# How would I do collision detection between a moving image at the bottom of the screen and falling objects without using sprites?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I have coded this code where there are various objects falling from the top of the screen and the frog at the bottom has to try and catch them. I cannot seem to do the collision detection with the frog and the falling objects following any tutorials as I have not use sprites and for some reason the rect functions aren't working either. I have no idea how to go about it anymore as no tutorial is working. Any help is appreciated !

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

fx1=random.randrange(0,300)
fx2=random.randrange(350,650)
fx3=random.randrange(700,950)
fy1=-50
fy2=-100
fy3=--200
fy1a=-300
fy2a=-400
fy3a=-500
#### fruits######
thingylist= ['fruit1.bmp','fruit2.bmp','fruit3.bmp','fruit4.bmp','fruit5.bmp','fruit1.bmp','fruit2.bmp','fruit3.bmp','fruit4.bmp','fruit5.bmp','naughty1.bmp','naughty2.bmp','naughty3.bmp',]
thing1=pygame.image.load(thingylist[(random.randrange(0,12))])
thing1.set_colorkey(pink)
thing1_rect=thing1.get_rect()
thing1_rect.centerx=(fx1)
thing1_rect.centery=(fy1)
thing2=pygame.image.load(thingylist[(random.randrange(0,12))])
thing2.set_colorkey(pink)
thing2_rect=thing2.get_rect()
thing2_rect.centerx=(fx2)
thing2_rect.centery=(fy2)
thing3=pygame.image.load(thingylist[(random.randrange(0,12))])
thing3.set_colorkey(pink)
thing3_rect=thing3.get_rect()
thing3_rect.centerx=(fx3)
thing3_rect.centery=(fy3)

fx1a=random.randrange(0,300)
fx2a=random.randrange(350,650)
fx3a=random.randrange(700,950)
thing4=pygame.image.load(thingylist[(random.randrange(0,12))])
thing4.set_colorkey(pink)
thing4_rect=thing4.get_rect()
thing4_rect.centerx=(fx1a)
thing4_rect.centery=(fy1a)
thing5=pygame.image.load(thingylist[(random.randrange(0,12))])
thing5.set_colorkey(pink)
thing5_rect=thing5.get_rect()
thing5_rect.centerx=(fx2a)
thing5_rect.centery=(fy2a)
thing6=pygame.image.load(thingylist[(random.randrange(0,12))])
thing6.set_colorkey(pink)
thing6_rect=thing6.get_rect()
thing6_rect.centerx=(fx3a)
thing6_rect.centery=(fy3a)

##thingylist=[thing1,thing2,thing3,thing4,thing5,thing6]
################collision###############






############ initialising sprites##############
frog= pygame.image.load('actual frog.bmp')
frog.set_colorkey(blue)
frog_rect=frog.get_rect()
frog_rect.centerx=(x)
frog_rect.centery=(y)



#########update display function###########
def update(x,y,fx1,fx2,fx3,fx1a,fx2a,fx3a,fy1,fy2,fy3,fy1a,fy2a,fy3a):
    gamedisplay.blit(bg,[0,0])
    gamedisplay.blit(frog,(x,y))
    gamedisplay.blit(thing1,(fx1,fy1))
    gamedisplay.blit(thing2,(fx2,fy2))
    gamedisplay.blit(thing3,(fx3,fy3))
    gamedisplay.blit(thing4,(fx1a,fy1a))
    gamedisplay.blit(thing5,(fx2a,fy2a))
    gamedisplay.blit(thing6,(fx3a,fy3a))
    label=font.render("score "+ str(score) ,1,textcolour)
    gamedisplay.blit(label,(750,10))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(50)



#########main game loop ############
while running == True:
    gamedisplay.blit(bg,[0,0])
    gamedisplay.blit(frog,(x,y))
    gamedisplay.blit(thing1,(fx1,fy1))
    gamedisplay.blit(thing2,(fx2,fy2))
    gamedisplay.blit(thing3,(fx3,fy3))
    gamedisplay.blit(thing4,(fx1a,fy1a))
    gamedisplay.blit(thing5,(fx2a,fy2a))
    gamedisplay.blit(thing6,(fx3a,fy3a))
    label=font.render("score "+ str(score) ,1,textcolour)
    gamedisplay.blit(label,(750,10))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.event.pump()
    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()


    ############collision detection##########
##    for t in thingylist:
##        if frog.rect.colliderect(thing_rect):
##            score=score+100
update(x,y,fx1,fx2,fx3,fx1a,fx2a,fx3a,fy1,fy2,fy3,fy1a,fy2a,fy3a)
```

Comment: first learn how to use `list` and `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `rect` of each "thing", and compare it with `frog_rect`.  The PyGame function `pygame.rect.colliderect()` can check this easily.  What is making this difficult with your current code, is you don't know the `rect` for each thing, only the `(x,y)`.

Since you do not wish to use Sprites, I humbly suggest you re-work the code to store each "thing" in a modest data-structure like a list of things, where each thing is a pair of `[ image, rect ]`.  This allows the code to simply loop over the list of "things" and perform operations on them.

```
# Create some things
thingylist = ['fruit1.bmp','fruit2.bmp','fruit3.bmp','fruit4.bmp','fruit5.bmp','fruit1.bmp','fruit2.bmp','fruit3.bmp','fruit4.bmp','fruit5.bmp','naughty1.bmp','naughty2.bmp','naughty3.bmp',]

all_things = []
for i in range( 10 ):
    new_thing_image  = thingylist[(random.randrange(0,12))]
    new_thing_rect   = new_thing_image.get_rect()
    new_thing_rect.x = random.randrange(0,950)
    new_thing_rect.y = -random.randrange(50,500)
    all_things.append( [ new_thing_image, new_thing_rect ] )
```

This list-of-things allows the code to say, loop over the list checking for collisions:

```
def checkCollision( frog_rect, things ):
    """ Find the first thing that collides with frog.
        Return the thing (removing it from the list), or None """
    collides_with = None
    for i in range( len( things) ):
        thing_rect = things[i][1]
        if ( frog_rect.colliderect( thing_rect ) ):
            collides_with = things.pop( i )
    return collides_with
```

Allowing the code to say:

```
thing_hit = checkCollision( frog_rect, all_things )
if ( thing_hit != None ):
    # We hit something!
    pass # TODO
```

Also for operations like painting all the things:

```
def drawThings( things ):
    for item in things:
        thing_image, thing_rect = item
        gamedisplay.blit( thing_image, ( thing_rect.x, thing_rect.y ) )
```

Which is much simpler than keeping track of all those separate co-ordinates.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice ! But the thing is now my objects will not fall from the top of the screen like they used to I have tried to make changes to accommodate this but none of them have worked. This is my current game falling code: `for thing in range (len(all_things)):
        thing_rect=all_things[i][1]
        thing_rect.y=thing_rect.y+fallingspeed` using this code only one of the 'things' falls from the top of the screen and the rest can be seen frozen at the top of the screen and they dont move

Comment: also this is my update subfunction if it is of any use: `def update(x,y,all_things):
    gamedisplay.blit(bg,[0,0])
    gamedisplay.blit(frog,(x,y))
    drawThings(all_things)
##    gamedisplay.blit(thing1,(fx1,fy1))
##    gamedisplay.blit(thing2,(fx2,fy2))
##    gamedisplay.blit(thing3,(fx3,fy3))
##    gamedisplay.blit(thing4,(fx1a,fy1a))
##    gamedisplay.blit(thing5,(fx2a,fy2a))
##    gamedisplay.blit(thing6,(fx3a,fy3a))
    label=font.render("score "+ str(score) ,1,textcolour)
    gamedisplay.blit(label,(750,10))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(50)`

Comment: also everywhere in your sample code when you wrote 'things' did you mean to say 'all_things' ?